# Is there a way to "split" one display so that it treated as two separate screens?

Tags: macos, display

Is there any app or hack which can split a monitor into multiple screens? So for instance, a 1920x1080 display could be treated by the operating system as though there were two 960x1080 screens connected instead.

Comment: It might help to specify exactly what you are wanting to do with those two screens (and if it is Apple specific). There may be other ways to accomplish whatever your goal is than to get the OS to treat one monitor as two.

Comment: @lemonginger: I mostly want to be able to full-screen zoom on apps within sub-windows. (It would also be nice if Lion's full-screen mode played nice with multi-window setups, but that's another subject...)

Lri: I'm fine with removing that, I'll check out the other question for alternatives.

Comment: ahhh, yeah not sure on that one. I agree that multi-monitor support in Lion so far is a big step backwards from SL. Hoping that 10.7.2 fixes some things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There is No: True Multi-Monitor Support for a Single Display

There is no way to get the OS to treat a single display as more than one display.

### You Can:  Fill Defined Sections of your Screen with an App

You can get very close to what you are looking for with a tool like [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) or [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/#divvyMac). They will allow you to fill sections of your screen with an app. Halves, quarters, etc.

### Update: Answer still largely accurate as of 7/2020

After many years a friend mentioned he came across this post. Here is an updated response:

You still can't do true Linux-like window management or split a large screen into multiple monitors. Mac OS has added to it's [Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_(software)) feature including the ability to have fractional spaces (two apps side by side) which is really just a first party version of the third part solution mentioned above. It is still very limited as a window management system and generally less useful than any of the third party tools mentioned in this thread so far.

You can find a pretty [thorough walk through of Spaces](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/10/12/how-to-use-spaces-apples-mostly-ignored-macos-mojave-productivity-feature) over at Apple Insider.

Also, today I use [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) (as mentioned by other commenters below). I find it to be the best modern answer to this question.

Comment: Another couple of options, just because different people prefer different ways of working, are http://www.trifleapps.com/arrange.html and http://spectacleapp.com/ . The latter is free and very good if all you need are the basics.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer re:  app or hack to get the OS to treat a single display as multiple displays.  The other answers are window management tools like Spaces as the author describes.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/397184/119271) for a true hardware solution.

Answer (score 10):

There's a major difference between [Window Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) and actually having the operating system, macOS, see one single monitor as two (or more) physical monitors.

The OP is asking for the latter.

> a 1920x1080 display **could be treated by the operating system as though there were two 960x1080 screens connected** instead.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

Until now, there have been no apps or hacks that would trick the OS into thinking there was two physical displays when there was only one.  The monitor, via [EDID data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data), tells the system what type and configuration the connected display has.  In order for the OS to see two separate monitors, the monitor itself must present as two separate displays.  This also *required* separate display interfaces.

The [LG 43UN700-B](http://radnex.us/LG_43UN700-B_Multi-Input-Display) is a true hardware answer to the question.  It has a true "4 screen split" that is supplied by 4 independent inputs.  These inputs can be from one source (your Mac) or from 4 different sources like your Mac, a camera, a video game console and your PC (or any other combination).  The Display's EDID info will tell the connected system(s) that it's either a single 43" monitor or 4 separate 21" monitors.

[image: LG 43UN700-B Multi-Input Display]

Other than the accepted answer, the other answers address the question with window management tools.  These tools simply automate the task of sizing and "snapping" the window to a particular location on the screen.  These apps do not present multiple physical monitors to the system.

#### TL;DR

Is there an app or a hack that can make macOS think a monitor is actually two (or more) separate monitors?  No.  However, circa 2020, LG has created a monitor that actually does this

Comment: This is actually what I'm interested in. I own LG 49WL95C (49 inch) monitor and I would like to split it into two different screens. The main reason for me is that I would like to swipe between MacOs spaces on half of the monitor but not the other half.

Comment: Does it support the feature as described in the answer?

Comment: It'd be nice if there a way to do this in software given the hardware limitations on number of external displays supported by the new M1 machines in particular. I agree that swiping through spaces on one portion of the screen would be very valuable.

Comment: @Allan It works flawlessly! Thanks for pointing that out. I knew my monitor supports showing multiple input sources at the same time but never occurred to me to connect the same laptop with two different cables to it. Now instead of one 49 inch screen I have two side-by-side 27" screens. 

Comment: Is there a name/keyword for this feature that LG offers? I ask because I'd like to keep an eye out for other monitors that might exist or come on the market that also support this feature. I've been wanting this for a long time.

Comment: Keyword from Amazon link: Four screen split - picture in Picture

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a software solution that answers the OP's request exactly, but in its place you might consider a *window manager*:

### Window managers

*Original answer*: Adding my vote for the window manager [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)! Excellent tool - as simple or complex as you need it to be, and keeps out of the way.

This is a tool that, like the ones mentioned in the other answer, lets you resize windows to fit defined sections of your screen.

---

*Update July 2019*: Since writing this answer, I have switched to using [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com) which is even simpler and more modern; matching my needs.

---

*Update October 2021*: I am now using a combination os [Swish](https://highlyopinionated.co/swish/) (mouse gestures for window management) and [Yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) (automatic or command-line driven window management)

Comment: StackExchnage sites show votes by clicking the up arrows not by extra answers/comments. However this is the first mention of moom so could you explain what it does

Answer (score 3):

Ever since the Mojave update you can hold click on the expand button:

[image]

of any window to go into multi-tasking view where the screen is split into two distinct window spaces.

Comment: You can also do this with Sierra

Answer (score 2):

Since El Capitan, you can zoom two windows to "full screen" in the same Space: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948

To the best of my knowledge, you can't rearrange the two applications within the Space (for example, splitting vertically instead of horizontally) other than swapping them side-to-side, nor have more than two windows in the same Space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BetterDummy](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDummy) to make your virtual displays, then do PIP window streaming without title bar. NOTE that the PIP streaming is only available with the $15 Pro version. I also believe that you need macOS Big Sur or newer.